# PHP XML without grouping

Tags: php, xml

I'll be using PHP to parse a SVG-file and I've done some tests with PHP SimpleXML that works very well BUT it groups all the objects with the same type together wich is not good for my SVG.

Say I have SVG file like this:

```
<svg>
   <g>SOME SVG</g>
   <path d="SOME X AND Y's"/>
   <g>SOME MORE SVG</g>
</svg>
```

Then Simple XML will group the same objects like:

```
[g][0] => 'SOME SVG'
[g][1] => 'SOME MORE SVG'
[path[0] => 'SOME AND X AND Y's'
```

This all works well for editing the data but when I then want to convert it back to SVG again I've lost the sort order of the objects! For normal XML this might not be a problem but for the SVG file the order of objects is also the layer sort order so if I convert the output back to SVG I would get:

```
<svg>
   <g>SOME SVG</g>
   <g>SOME MORE SVG</g>
   <path d="SOME X AND Y's"/>
</svg>
```

And then maybe the "SOME MORE SVG"-group will overlap and be on top of the PATH graphics even thought the PATH was supposed to be on top of the "SOME MORE SVG"-group. How do I fix this?

I've seen thats I can add for example order="X" to all objects but since the file have a sort order from the start already, this seems unnecessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/book.dom.php), you don't have that problem:

```
$svg = '<svg>
   <g>SOME SVG</g>
   <path d="SOME X AND Y\'s"/>
   <g>SOME MORE SVG</g>
</svg>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($svg);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// selecting only g nodes directly under svg (root node)
$gNodes = $xpath->query('/svg/g'); // $gNodes will be of type: DOMNodeList with every element being of type: DOMElement, which extends DOMNode

foreach ($gNodes as $gNode) {
    // doing stuff with $gNode
    $gNode->nodeValue .= ' adding stuff';
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg>
   <g>SOME SVG adding stuff</g>
   <path d="SOME X AND Y's"/>
   <g>SOME MORE SVG adding stuff</g>
</svg>
```

Useful links:

- [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/class.domelement.php)
- [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/class.domnode.php)
- [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/class.domnodelist.php)
- [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/class.domxpath.php)

Comment: This is looking good! I'm new to DOM objects but how do I get the SVG from inside each of the <g>'s in this example in its own variable? Like:

$arr[0] = "<g>SOME SVG</g>";
$arr[1] = "<path d="SOME X AND Y\'s"/>";
$arr[2] = <g>SOME MORE SVG</g>;

Comment: You could collect these in an $arr array, but I would not recommend this as I tend to work directly on the dom structure. Maybe you can give a more detailed example of how you would want to manipulate these values, and I will updated the sample code accordingly.

Comment: I want to get all <g> objects in the first level of the xml and the data inside of them. I need to be able to get them each to a variable because each first level <g> contains data that will be loaded on different pages. Does this make sence to you?

Comment: @Carl Bengtsson I changed the code to incorporate `DOMXPath` and added some manual links for further reading. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! But I still cant find how I get the full xml from each gNode? I tried using echo $gNode->textContent but that returned nothing. I need something like ->saveXml() but only for the $gNode.

Comment: @Carl Bengtsson See http://php.net/manual/domdocument.savexml.php You can use it as: `$dom->saveXml($gNode)` and will return the xml starting from this node (and children).

Comment: @Yoshi Sorry I gave you the wrong example. The one above works fine but when I use real SVG code like: <svg>
   <g><path d="SOME X AND Y"/></g>
   <g>SOME MORE SVG adding stuff</g>
</svg>
It return nothing. How do I solve this? I need all the xml inside of the <g>. So in this example 0=<path d="SOME X AND Y"/>, 1=SOME MORE SVG adding stuff. Sorry for being slow but I just cant get this to work.

Comment: @Yoshi Ahh my misstake, should have had another Coffee... SVG Was outputed as it should but since it's SVG it wasnt visible in broswer, only in source code :) Thank you so much for the help! Now I will get to work.